# Problems with Multiple DbContexts with differents connections

Tags: c#, wpf, oracle, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

When I create multiple DbContext with differents connection,  extra connections was created to the database. Is it possible to have only 2 connections for my sample?

```
var vOracleConnection1 = new OracleConnection(vConnectionString);
vOracleConnection1.Open();

var vDbContext1 = new DbContext(existingConnection    : vOracleConnection1
                               ,contextOwnsConnection : false
                               );
vUser1 = vDbContext1.users.FirstOrDefault(vUsr => vUsr.Code = 123);

var vOracleConnection2 = new OracleConnection(vConnectionString);
vOracleConnection2.Open();

var vDbContext2 = new DbContext(existingConnection    : vOracleConnection2
                               ,contextOwnsConnection : false
                               );

vUser2 = vDbContext2.users.FirstOrDefault(vUsr=> vUsr.Code = 456);
```

Connections to Oracle Server with 1 DbContext I have 1 connection :

> Program   Machine OSUser  Server  SID Status  Terminal    Type    SQL_ID
>
> 1- LORRFR SERVER\WKS-LORRFR   lorrfr  DEDICATED   361 INACTIVE    WKS-LORRFR  USER

Connections to Oracle Server with 2 DbContexts I have 7 connections :

> Program   Machine OSUser  Server  SID Status  Terminal    Type    SQL_ID
>
> 1- LORRFR  SERVER\WKS-LORRFR   lorrfr  DEDICATED   18  INACTIVE    WKS-LORRFR  USER
> 2- LORRFR  SERVER\WKS-LORRFR   lorrfr  DEDICATED   24  INACTIVE    WKS-LORRFR  USER
> 3- LORRFR  SERVER\WKS-LORRFR   lorrfr  DEDICATED   25  INACTIVE    WKS-LORRFR  USER
> 4- LORRFR  SERVER\WKS-LORRFR   lorrfr  DEDICATED   367 INACTIVE    WKS-LORRFR  USER
> 5- LORRFR  SERVER\WKS-LORRFR   lorrfr  DEDICATED   361 INACTIVE    WKS-LORRFR  USER
> 6- LORRFR  SERVER\WKS-LORRFR   lorrfr  DEDICATED   366 INACTIVE    WKS-LORRFR  USER
> 7- LORRFR  SERVER\WKS-LORRFR   lorrfr  DEDICATED   358 INACTIVE    WKS-LORRFR  USER

After several time we come back to 2 connections :

> Program   Machine OSUser  Server  SID Status  Terminal    Type    SQL_ID
>
> 1- LORRFR  SERVER\WKS-LORRFR   lorrfr  DEDICATED   361 INACTIVE    WKS-LORRFR  USER
> 2- LORRFR  SERVER\WKS-LORRFR   lorrfr  DEDICATED   18  INACTIVE    WKS-LORRFR  USER

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably related to connection pooling.

There are several parameters you can specify in oracle connection string ( https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/win.101/b10117/features001.htm ) but in your case `Pooling=false` should be enough.
BTW, turning off connection pooling could (will) decrease performances.

Comment: Thank you!  It solve my problem.  For the performance, in my case, I keep my connection open until I close the window so it not affect any performance.